# Why is KB3170455 being repeatedly installed and uninstalled?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Windows Update wants to reboot. [I have a bunch of things open right now](https://xkcd.com/1328/) so I looked at the update history to see if it's *really* necessary. This is what I saw:

[image: Pending uninstall]

Transcription of the screenshot:

```
Name                                                                                      Status      Importance  Date Installed
(Uninstall:) Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3170455)              Pending     Important   8/4/2017
Definition Update for Microsoft Endpoint Protection - KB2461484 (Definition 1.249.608.0)  Successful  Important   8/3/2017
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3170455)                           Successful  Important   7/31/2017
(Uninstall:) Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3170455)              Successful  Important   7/31/2017
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3170455)                           Successful  Important   7/31/2017
```

The second line is apparently unrelated, but the others all mention KB3170455. It's been installed and uninstalled once already, then installed again, and now it has another pending uninstall. I never asked for it to be uninstalled. It just happened on its own, like all the previous instances.

What causes an update to be automatically uninstalled? Has it been "recalled" because it causes more problems than it fixes? Why would they then reissue it with the same name/number? Is this a known problem with this specific update?

Comment: Does this behavior still happen after a reboot?

Comment: KB3170455 Was released 14 months ago.....Windows Update is erroneously downloading that update

Comment: I would start with the Windows Update repair tool:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-windows-update-troubleshooter  If the update times out (hangs) during installation, it will eventually uninstall.  If the trouble persists you can check the Windows Update log for details on why it is failing:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/902093/how-to-read-the-windowsupdate-log-file